# WriteConcernResult result null mongodb

Tags: mongodb

When trying to update with mongodb by using the below code my result is getting null: in C#

```
public bool UpdateContact(string id, Contact item)       
{
    IMongoQuery query = Query.EQ("_id", id);
    item.LastModified = DateTime.UtcNow;
    IMongoUpdate update = Update
        .Set("Email", item.Email)
        .Set("LastModified", DateTime.UtcNow)
        .Set("Name", item.Name)
        .Set("Phone", item.Phone);
    WriteConcernResult result = _contacts.Update(query, update);
    return result.UpdatedExisting;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what language this is? Looks like about 4 atm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not using the new connection style for the C# driver (and likely other drivers), your connection may be configured to not have a [WriteConcern by default](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/Release%20Notes/Release%20Notes%20v1.7.md).

If there's no WriteConcern configured, the C# API will return a `null` as the result for the code you provided (see [Update](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.7/html/a2464e96-3ee4-b763-f549-0fab88b5aea0.htm) for more info)

For example, if your connection is like this:

```
var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";
var server = MongoServer.Create(connectionString); // deprecated
var database = server.GetDatabase("test"); // WriteConcern defaulted to Unacknowledged
```

That would be configured to for no write concern.

You should be using this style (as of the C# 1.7 driver):

```
var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";
var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
var server = client.GetServer();
var database = server.GetDatabase("test"); // WriteConcern defaulted to Acknowledged
```

The difference is that you need to use the `MongoClient` class (and get the `MongoServer` and the `MongoDatabase` from that object instance).